# AngularJS Module Injection logic understand

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependencies

Im learning AngularJS and his separation of concerns using module.
I have created a simple app that is composed by an index.html that is the view, and two file .js, one for the controller and one for my own service.
The question is the following: How i can inject the .js file that contains the service, into the one for the controller?

That's my controller.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $window,$interval,$location) {
    $scope.appUrl = $location.absUrl();
    $scope.port = $location.port();
    $scope.protocol = $location.protocol();
    $scope.winWidth = $window.innerWidth;
    $interval(function(){
        $scope.winWidth = $window.innerWidth;
    }, 1);
});
```

and this is the date-time-service.js

```
var service = angular.module('myApp',[]);
service.factory('dateTimeService', function() {
    var dateTimeSvc = {};
    dateTimeSvc.getData = function(){
        return new Date().toDateString();
    }
    dateTimeSvc.getTime = function(){
        return new Date().toTImeString();
    }
    return dateTimeSvc;
})
```

Obviosly i know that i can create a single .js file that contains both and call it into my view, but i want to understand the logic behind the dependencies injection starting with this "stupid" application, and then extends it to a little bit larger applications.
Thanks you all anticipately for all the answers!

Answer (score 0):

We don't inject the js file. We inject dependencies.

If you are looking into how to dynamically inject modules in run time after angular context is initialisized -- its here http://blog.getelementsbyidea.com/load-a-module-on-demand-with-angularjs/
I have implemented this long ago where I dynamically call modules from server and inject it into my angular context based on which screen the user is in.

Comment: So, if i have a dependency in a file, how i can call it in my controller file?

Comment: myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $window,$interval,$location,ABCD) -------->> 

       here  ABCD is the dependency that you are injecting..